# Django DataTable with Dynamic Models

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, datatables

I want to read a csv or text file then create a DataTable to allow users to search and filter the loaded file.

I currently have pre-defined models for sample csv files but the challenge is not knowing what file format (columns) the user will load to view and query.

Is there a way to simply load a file (csv or text) in Django then interact with the data (DataTables preferred) via the browser? Thanks

I currently use [django-ajax-datatable](https://github.com/morlandi/django-ajax-datatable) and it's great but requires models to be pre-defined.

Comment: user uploads the csv file?

Comment: Yes but in this case I think the user will provide a path to the csv file since it will be a relatively large file and wouldn't want to upload that. If the path is given, then the data can be open and read instead of uploading via UI.